# Quoted and Unquoted comma separated list in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server

I've a requirement where I need to select a column in a SQL table into two separate fields containing comma separated values - one should be quoted and the other one should unquoted.

So for example, if the table has the values a b c d e in a single column, my select SQL statement should return two fields - one field containing the values 'a','b','c','d','e' and the other one containing the values a,b,c,d,e.

I'm running the following SQL statement to achieve this:

```
SELECT 
    SUBSTRING((SELECT TOP 100 ''',''' + CAST(sales_id AS NVARCHAR(50)) 
               FROM sales_order_header 
               WHERE (status = 0) 
               ORDER BY updated_datetime, 1 
               FOR XML PATH('')),3,2147483647) + '''' AS quoted, 
    SUBSTRING((SELECT TOP 100 ',' + CAST(sales_id AS NVARCHAR(50)) 
               FROM sales_order_header 
               WHERE (status = 0) 
               ORDER BY updated_datetime, 1 
               FOR XML PATH('')),2,2147483647) + '' AS unquoted
```

However, I had a scenario where the results for "quoted" and "unquoted" column were different even though I am running the same "SELECT" statement in the SUBSTRING function.

What is the best way to achieve what I want to ?

Is there a way to write a SQL statement such that it queries the table just once and reuses the results for both columns rather than running the "SELECT" statement twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can avoid the repeated duplication of the query by building the basic query into a CTE or derived table. Assuming `sales_id` is numeric, building the Unquoted version from the Quoted version can be achieved by replacing out the quotes:

```
WITH MyCte(Col) AS
(
    SELECT TOP 100 ''',''' + CAST(sales_id AS NVARCHAR(50))
        FROM sales_order_header 
        WHERE (status = 0) 
        ORDER BY updated_datetime, 1 FOR XML PATH('')
)
SELECT SUBSTRING(Col, 3,2147483647) + '''' AS quoted, 
       SUBSTRING(Replace(Col, '''', ''),2,2147483647) + '' AS unquoted
FROM MyCte;
```